# Samba erases content of files when saving

Tags: debian, samba

Samba SMB share hosted on Debian "Jessie" in a private home network setup.

Can connect to share, open files and copy files to / from share OK.

Attempting to make any changes to a file on the share (example: edit a text document) results in `ALL CONTENT OF THE FILE ERASED`. File itself remains on share but with file size of 0.

Shared directory on the server has permissions 775.

Have tried chown combinations of root:root and root:users without success.

Settings smb.conf for share sets both `writable=yes` and `browsable=yes`. Have tried combinations of `force user`, `force group` and `create mask` without success.

Using:

```
security = user
encrypt passwords = true
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
```

EDIT:
I seem to have narrowed down the issue to Leafpad, specifically. Other apps seem to be able to edit documents on the share OK. Ironically, I was using Leafpad as the simplest tool to test opening and editing.

Comment: Is "ALL CONTENT OF THE FILE ERASED" an error message that you get from something? If so, what produces this message? Or are you just using formatted text to emphasise the problem at hand? Is there anything relevant in the log files under `/var/log/samba`? How much disk space do you have on the partition hosting your Samba share (`df -h /path/to/samba/share/...`)

Answer (score 0):

One of the few reasons for a file being truncated unexpectedly is lack of disk space.

It would be worth confirming the amount of available disk space using `df -h`. For example, if the share is hosted on `/home/share` then the command `df -h /home/share` will provide the necessary information.

```
$ df -h /home/share
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        15G   12G  2.1G  85% /
```

In this example there is 85% used, so 15% available on the root partition hosting `/home/share`.

Typically 5% of the available disk space is reserved for `root`, so unless there is at least this amount of disk space files cannot be created or extended except by the `root` user. (Samba does not generally write files with `root` ownership.)

Answer (score 0):

**This is a known bug**:

- [Bug #708829 “Text truncated when I save a txt file during a sftp...” : Bugs : leafpad package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/leafpad/+bug/708829) has a number of dups linked to it and provides further links
- [#680418 - gvfs-fuse: Wrongly sucessful posix fwrite call on a gvfs sftp mount can lead to data loss - Debian Bug report logs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=680418) + [1295007 – Non-GIO (POSIX) API call to save data truncates file to 0 bytes.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1295007) suggest a cause at a deeper level, but apparently, Leafpad is one of only a few applications where the bug triggers